# Entity Framework Updating Many to Many relationships properly

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In my `School EF Model`, I have `Kids` and `Tutorials` in many-to-many relationship.
Let's assume both Kids and Tutorials have existing items in them, now we just want to change their existing relationships. That is, to add/delete some tutorials from a kid.

```
var kid; //the request target to modify relationships
//kid.Tutorials has the old existing relationships to be modified by add/del
var tutorialsToAdd; //the request to add relationships
var tutorialsToDel; //the request to del relationships
using (var conn = new SchoolEFModels(efConnectionStr)) {
    conn.Kids.Attach(kid);
    kid.Tutorials.ForEach(t => conn.Tutorials.Attach(t));
    kid.Tutorials.AddRange(tutorialsToAdd); //simple add extension in batch
    kid.Tutorials.RemoveRange(tutorialsToDel); //simple del extension in batch
    conn.SaveChanges();
}
```

When I do this, I got an exception saying:

`"Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Tutorials'. The duplicate key value is (10)."`

I can see EF is trying to create new Tutorial items instead of updating the existing relationship for me. Which is what I don't want. You misunderstood me EF!

What is wrong with my code? How do I make it update Many-to-Many relationships?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn166926.aspx

Comment: @GertArnold, it is up selling MVC Scaffolding to me. didn't specifically talked about many-to-many update handling. My app has a different structure than that. So I am still lost :(

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

Adding/removing it will make EntityState turn to Added/Deleted. Therefore, causing it to reinsert existing Ids as the article mentioned, thank Gert there for the link.

So, if you modify each of the `conn.entry(kid/tutorials).State` to `EntityState.Modified` and then call `conn.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();` then `conn.SaveChanges();` it will only update the many-to-many table as expected.

UPDATE:

One thing you need to be careful tho. If the in-memory objects list of Kids and Tutorials are linked to each other. e.g. `Kids[0].Tutorials[0] == Tutorials[0] && Tutorial[0].Kids[0] == Kids[0]` EF will not be able to handle this dead loop for you. You need to break this circular link first.
To do so, my approach is to open a Connection and read the Kid out Includes(Tutorials), and then use the result to update many to many relationship, but not to use the in-memory objects.